# popup can't stay in the center of screen due to background page scrolling back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have this problem that the page is scrolling to the top when I click a button to open a popup window.

So, if I scroll down the page to almost bottom, there is a button 'submit', when clicked, a popup window will open, which supposed to open in the center of the screen. But once 'submit' is clicked, the page scrolls up to the top, which makes the popup is not visible(the popup window is in the center of the old page before it scrolls to the top). What's more, if I scroll page down, close the popup window, click 'submit' again, the page will not scroll to the top, and the popup is indeed in the center of the window. It's only the first time when the button is clicked, the page will scroll to the top by itself.

I want the popup window keep in the center of the screen all the time, I used `data-position-to="window"` to achieve this. I believe the reason it's not in the center is because the page itself scrolls to the top. Wondering how should I do to fix this?

This is my popup :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="feedbackValidationError" data-position-to="window" data-dismissible="false" data-history="false" data-overlay-theme="a" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1 class="center">Form Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content popupPadding">
            <p>Please answer to at least one of the questions</p>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="feedbackValidationErrorButton">OK</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Code I use to open popup:

```
$("#feedbackValidationError").popup("open");
```

and for close the popup:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#FeedbackEnter',
     function () {
         $("#feedbackValidationErrorButton").on("click", 
             function () {
                  $("#feedbackValidationError").popup("close");
             }
         );
      }
 );
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `data-position-to="window"` means nothing to us unless we can see your js code. Please post so we can see what this attribute means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the behavior that you are trying to describe in your question. https://jsfiddle.net/5mrybr1v/3/

To solve that you can show popUp after scroll.

`window.scrollTo(0,0); 
$("#feedbackValidationError").popup("open");`

https://jsfiddle.net/5mrybr1v/4/

Comment: The first link doesn't reproduce my problem. But the solution really solved my problem. It's amazing, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to handle this. `position: fixed` will keep the element fixed to the window instead of the position in the document.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLeh24z1/1/

No matter where you scroll it stays in the same position.

```
.popup {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: But I want the popup shows in the center of the screen, it shouldn't be fixed. I mean the user may scroll the page to any position, but the popup will always be in the center of current position.

Comment: @YabinSong look at the fiddle. It is in the center no matter where you scroll. Sorry had just updated it to do that as you added comment.

Comment: It doesn't work.. It makes the right half of popup goes out of screen.

Comment: The fiddle is in the middle of the screen. I think there is a lot of your code not being shared so whatever you copied and pasted from my simple example to show you how position fixed works isn't enough. I gave a very simple example. It may need to be extended in your code to work but what I gave is the general idea.

Comment: I updated my question, I posted my popup <div>. I don't see any css for this div.. This is what I can see in the code.